# Hide dynamically generated Divs with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, dynamically-generated, generated

This is the jquery I use

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".post").hide();
     $(".show_hide").show();

  $(".show_hide").click(function(){
  $(".post").slideToggle();
  });
});
</script>
```

I'm using json api to generate the content

```
<?php
$region_api = $_GET['server'];
if($region_api == 'euw')
    $api = 'http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/board/devtracker.php?format=json';   
elseif($region_api == 'eune')
    $api = 'http://eune.leagueoflegends.com/board/devtracker.php?format=json';
elseif($region_api == 'na')
    $api = 'http://na.leagueoflegends.com/board/devtracker.php?format=json';

$json_file = file_get_contents($api, null, null);
$json_array = json_decode($json_file, true);
?>
<div id="content">
<?php
foreach($json_array as $i =>$value){
    $userid = $json_array[$i]['userid'];
    $username = $json_array[$i]['username'];
    $usertitle = $json_array[$i]['usertitle'];
    $threadid = $json_array[$i]['threadid'];
    $threadtitle = $json_array[$i]['threadtitle'];
    $forumtitle = $json_array[$i]['forumtitle'];
    $postid = $json_array[$i]['postid'];
    $postcontent = $json_array[$i]['pagetext'];
    $avatardateline = $json_array[$i]['avatardateline'];
?>
</br>
<a href="#" class="show_hide"><?php echo $threadtitle; ?></a>
<div class="post">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="user_info">
            <div class="username">
            <?php echo $username; ?></br>
            <?php echo $usertitle; ?>
            </div>
            <div class="avatar"><img src='http://<?php echo $region_api;?>.leagueoflegends.com/board/image.php?u=<?php echo $userid; ?>&dateline=<?php echo $avatardateline; ?>'></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class='post_text'><p><?php echo $postcontent; ?></p></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
    }
    ?>
</div>
    <?php
?>
```

This might not be the most optimal way of doing it, but i'm having problem hiding individual divs. Instead when you click the title it shows/hides all the divs
example
http://leagueoflegends-bg.com/redtrack.php?server=euw#

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
$(".show_hide").click(function(i){
  $(".post").eq(i).slideToggle();
  });
```

OR

```
 $(".show_hide").click(function(){
      $(".post",this).slideToggle();
      });
```

Comment: hmm i tried both the functions and the divs just stay hidden and when i click the title it does nothing.